# Memory problem with SQLite inserts on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, memory-management, sql-insert

I have an app that needs to do multiple inserts, reading values from a file.
To do it I begin a transaction, prepare the statement, do the bind with values (read from the file) and exec the insert. All of it in loop for all rows of the file.
All worked fine, until I tried with a file with a milion of rows.
In this case I see the RAM increase until app crash.

This is how I implemented it (obviously I post simplified code on my problem, without use methods, without checking for errors, ecc..).

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

// OPEN DATABASE
sqlite3 *db;
if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"NON HO APERTO");
}

//BEGIN TRANSACTION
char * sErrMsg = 0;
sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, &sErrMsg);
if(sErrMsg != NULL)
    NSLog(@"Error starting transaction");


//PREPARE STATEMENT
char sSQL [BUFFER_SIZE] = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table1 (Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6,Field7,Field8,Field9,Field10,Field11,Field12,Field13,Field14,Field15,Field16,Field17) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
const char * tail = 0;
int res = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,  sSQL, BUFFER_SIZE, &stmt, &tail);
if(res != SQLITE_OK){
    NSLog(@"Error preparing the statement: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}

int counter = 0;

//BIND VALUES AND EXEC
FILE * pFile = fopen ([insertsFilePath_test UTF8String],"r");
while (!feof(pFile)) {

    char line [BUFFER_SIZE];
    fgets (line, sizeof(char)*BUFFER_SIZE, pFile);

    NSString* readLine = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:line];

    NSArray *values = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[readLine dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:NULL];
    for(int i = 0; i < [values count];i++){
        int res = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, i+1, [values[i] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        if(res != SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"There is an error with the bind of values: %d error code.",res);
        }
    }
    sqlite3_step(stmt);
    sqlite3_reset(stmt);

    counter++;

    //POINT A


}//while
fclose (pFile);

//END TRANSACTION
char * endTrErrMsg = 0;
sqlite3_exec(db, "END TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, &endTrErrMsg);
if(endTrErrMsg != NULL){
    NSLog(@"Error closing transaction");
}

sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
sqlite3_close(db);

NSLog(@"FINISH %d",counter++);
```

When I found the problem I tried to release some of SQLite memory every X rows, adding at the comment "//POINT A" something like:

```
if((counter % 80000) == 0 ){
  int bytes_freed = sqlite3_release_memory(AMOUNT_OF_MEM_TO_RELEASE);
  NSLog(@"Freed %d",bytes_freed);
  sqlite3_db_release_memory(db);
}
```

But "bytes_freed" was always 0, and I did not see even a slight change in the RAM graph.
I noticed that when the process finish (all rows written and connection with db closed) the system release the memory correctly.
So I tried to close transaction, release memory, finalize statement, close connection with db, reopen it, prepare statement again and start a new transaction.
Code change at POINT A:

```
if((counter % 80000) == 0 ){
        char * sErrMsg = 0;
        sqlite3_exec(db, "END TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, &sErrMsg);
        if(sErrMsg != NULL){
            NSLog(@"Error closing transaction");
        }

        int bytes_freed = sqlite3_release_memory(AMOUNT_OF_MEM_TO_RELEASE);
        NSLog(@"Freed %d",bytes_freed);
        sqlite3_db_release_memory(db);

        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        sqlite3_close(db);


        if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Error opening db");
        }

        //PREPARE STATEMENT AGAIN
        int res = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,  sSQL, BUFFER_SIZE, &stmt, &tail);
        if(res != SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"Error preparing the statement: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }

        sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, &sErrMsg);
        if(sErrMsg != NULL){
            NSLog(@"Error opening transaction");
        }
    }
```

Nothing changed.
Someone know why?

Does anyone know how I should face the problem?

Comment: Try using `@autoreleasepool` inside your `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you very much! You save me, I lost a lot of time looking for a solution